# Placeholder evaluation of lua code

Tags: lua

I have an application that uses lua files for some of its more obscure configuration options.  As such it mostly contains calls into the app to create things and alter properties; most C functions don't have a return value but some do.

I now have a need to read these same configuration files into a different application, and perform significantly different things when the functions are called (so I can't use common code).  In addition, I'm only interested in a subset of the possible functions, and I think I can get away with by default ignoring (and/or returning nil) any other function call.

So I'm wondering what the best approach is here.  How (from a C++ app), can I load and execute a lua script such that expressions etc are evaluated as normal but I can intercept and process certain app-defined C functions while simply ignoring (returning nil if required) calls to any other C functions?

(Note: I do have access to the vocabulary of the original app, which mostly uses luabind; I could just use the same definitions and change the implementation, but that's too fragile since the original app can have more functions added to it later.  I would like something more generic.)

---

The goal is to get a bit of C code which I can use as a generic placeholder; the end result being "anything that's defined (standard library routines, functions defined in Lua, and C functions explicitly registered), call it as normal; for anything else, call one specific routine that simply does nothing, instead of raising an error".  And preferably something compatible with luabind.

The whole process is initiated by a bit of C code that sets up the Lua environment, loads a set of files, calls one function, and then destroys the environment.  There won't be anything ongoing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a __call metamethod for nil:

```
debug.setmetatable(nil, { __call=function () end })
```

The _index metamethod for _G or other tables does not work because the name is resolved *before* the call.

(You don't need to use the debug API or library if you're setting this from C.)

Comment: I've ticked this one (for now) because it seems to work a bit better than the other options thus far, although it did require registering the tables/subtables containing functions in advance as well.  (Which is ok, but it'd be nice if this could be dealt with automatically too.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can add __index to the table above:

debug.setmetatable(nil, { __call=function () end, __index=function() end })

This will make a.b return nil if a is not defined.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but I've been working on other projects for a while.  Using __index as well seems to do what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about using [setfenv](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv) and a [metatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8)?  You can replace global environment table of certain function with an empty table.  And then, set the placeholder function to ignore C-defined function.

```
local env = {}  -- empty environment
local metatbl = {}
function metatbl.__index (tbl, key)  -- provides placeholder function
    return function()
        print(key .. " called")
        return(nil)
    end
end

setmetatable(env, metatbl)

function samplefunc()  -- your Lua code goes here
    globalfunction "xyz"   -- calls placeholder function
end

setfenv(samplefunc, env)
samplefunc()
```

If you want to use build-in function such as `print`, you can push it into env talbe like:

```
local env = {print = print}
```

Comment: Sorry, possibly I didn't explain this properly.  I want all the standard Lua library functions to still work as normal (though having said that, it would be useful to ignore certain ones such as the file i/o functions).  And I don't want to write more lua code; the replacement functions are replacing C functions and should themselves be written in C, and the code to set things up should also be in C.

Comment: @Miral: Your issue with the standard library functions was covered at the end of this answer. Also, anything written in Lua can also be written as C (even though it will be more difficult).  In addition, luaL_dostring() could be used to load similar Lua code from within C.

Comment: @gwell: Kind of, except that requires each thing I want to work to be added individually, which isn't that great.

I tried a variation on this which set env to getfenv(0) instead of {}.  This worked ok for global functions but not those in subtables, and gave a fairly obscure (to the user) error in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some way of differentiating the C functions from the ordinary Lua functions in your script, you can iterate over all functions defined in your Lua system, and for each C function that isn't on the list of functions you care about, replace that function's implementation with a simple nil-returning one.  This is really easy if all the c-binding functions are defined tidily together in a table; if they're in `_G` you have a bit of a job ahead of you.  The functions you *do* care about get bound via luabind as normal.

Comment: Some are global and some are in tables (and some are in sub-tables).  In this case I'm happy with assuming no errors, so basically anything that is already defined as a function must be a lua function and anything that is unknown might be either a C function or a table name.

I do know the names of the tables and the functions that currently exist, but I would *like* to not rely on that knowledge, since the original app is extensible.